# is this example is mvc method or not

Tags: ios

is this the way to code for mvc?

model:-

```
typealias JSONDictionary = [String:Any]

class EventModel: NSObject {

    var name :String!
      init?(dictionary :JSONDictionary) {

        guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String else{

                return
        }

        self.name = name
           }
}
```

datasourcemodel:-

```
class EventDataSourceModel: NSObject {

    var dataListArray:Array<EventModel>? = []


    init(array :Array<[String:Any]>?) {
        super.init()
        var newArray:Array<[String:Any]> = []
        if array == nil{

            newArray = self.getJsonDataStored2()
        }
        else{
            newArray = array!

        }

        var datalist:Array<EventModel> = []
        for dict in newArray{

            let model = EventModel(dictionary: dict)

            datalist.append(model!)
        }
        self.dataListArray = datalist
    }
}

typealias dummyDataSource2 =  EventDataSourceModel
extension dummyDataSource2{

    func getJsonDataStored2() ->Array<Dictionary<String,String>>{

        let jsonArray = [["id":"201","name":"Dosa Fest","imageurl":"","location":"Doha,Qatar","date":"Jan 2018","place":"Shiraz Garden"],["id":"202","name":"Organic Vegan Fest","imageurl":"","location":"Doha,Qatar","date":"15 Jan 2018 30 Jan 2018","place":"Evergreen Organics"],["id":"203","name":"Food Of Life Time","imageurl":"","location":"Doha,Qatar","date":"Jan 2018","place":"Turkey Central"],["id":"204","name":"Tea Time","imageurl":"","location":"Doha,Qatar","date":"Jan 2018","place":"Doha Food Mall"],["id":"205","name":"Dosa Fest","imageurl":"","location":"Doha,Qatar","date":"Jan 2018","place":"Shiraz Garden"],["id":"206","name":"Organic Vegan Fest","imageurl":"","location":"Doha,Qatar","date":"15 Jan 2018 30 Jan 2018","place":"Evergreen Organics"],["id":"207","name":"Food Of Life Time","imageurl":"","location":"Doha,Qatar","date":"Jan 2018","place":"Turkey Central"],["id":"208","name":"Tea Time","imageurl":"","location":"Doha,Qatar","date":"Jan 2018","place":"Doha Food Mall"]] as Array<Dictionary<String,String>>

        return jsonArray
    }
}
```

controller:-

```
class EventViewController: UIViewController ,UITableViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var datasourceModel:EventDataSourceModel!

    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?, withdatasourcemodel datasource:EventDataSourceModel) {

        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)

       datasourceModel = datasource

    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)!

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let identifier = "eventcell"
        var cell: EventCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? EventCell

        if cell == nil {
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "EventCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? EventCell
        }

        cell.setEventData(events:datasourceModel.dataListArray![indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

finally view:-

```
class QM_EventCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var location: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var date: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageurl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var place: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var images: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

    }

    func setEventData(events:QM_EventModel)
    {
        self.name.text = events.name

    }
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

I am new to this field.I am own learning .So i don,t know whether the method doing is correct or wrong.i need to develop the project using mvc.For that i refer many website about mvc method using swift.i know to do in mvvm ,but how the changes will come to mvc i am little bit confusion .
Is this way needed to separate.Or if wrong please tell how to do

Comment: is this correct or not

Comment: can anyone tell is this coding correct or not.

Comment: 1) Clean up the code, as all the spaces make it unreadable. 2) This is not a question about any errors or problems with your code. 3) You do not have to follow the MVC method, use what you find easiest. 4) Check the Apple website here for what MVC is: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html

Comment: @George_E_2 i just want to know,whether i uploaded code is mvc or not?is it correct or wrong

Comment: SE has a specific site for codereview, you might want to ask this there